# MultinomialNB: ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

In trying a Multinomial NB classifier on Kaggle's training/test sets, I get an odd ValueError. My (practice) goal is to just predict whether passengers are male or female based on their name, which goes into a CountVectorizer.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-ad69ee9ed02b> in <module>()
     12 
     13 # classifier prediction - for test set now!
---> 14 predict_Test = nb.predict(name_test)
     15 score = accuracy_score(sex_test, predictions, normalize=True)
     16 print score

C:\Users\Evan Chow\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.pyc in predict(self, X)
     61             Predicted target values for X
     62         """
---> 63         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     64         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
     65 

C:\Users\Evan Chow\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.pyc in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
    455         """Calculate the posterior log probability of the samples X"""
    456         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X)
--> 457         return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
    458                 + self.class_log_prior_)
    459 

C:\Users\Evan Chow\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.pyc in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
     81         return ret
     82     else:
---> 83         return np.dot(a, b)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

---

My code is:

```
rawDataTrain = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
trainData = pd.concat([rawDataTrain.Name, rawDataTrain.Sex], axis=1)

# get name, sex training data
cv_train = CountVectorizer(min_df = 0)
cv_train.fit(trainData.Name)
name_train = cv_train.transform(trainData.Name).toarray() # name_train
sex_train = np.asarray(trainData.Sex, dtype='S') # name_test

# get name, sex testing data
rawDataTest = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
testData = pd.concat([rawDataTest.Name, rawDataTest.Sex], axis=1)
cv_test = CountVectorizer(min_df = 0)
cv_test.fit(testData.Name)
name_test = cv_test.transform(testData.Name).toarray() # name test
sex_test = np.asarray(testData.Sex, dtype='S') # sex test

# classifier prediction - test quickly on training set. you should get 1.0
predictionsTrain = nb.predict(name_train)
scoreTrain = accuracy_score(sex_train, predictionsTrain, normalize=True)
print scoreTrain # returns probability of 1.0

# classifier prediction - this is what goes weird!
predict_Test = nb.predict(name_test)
score = accuracy_score(sex_test, predictions, normalize=True)
print score
```

Also, the dimensions of name_train, name_test, sex_train, and sex_test are:

(891, 1509)
(418, 825)
(891,) 
(418,)

It seems that the first coordinate of name_train and name_test need to be the same, but if that were true, prediction would only work on matrices with the same # of samples as the training set! Any thoughts on how to get rid of this ValueError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to have the same *second* dimension (i.e., same number of columns).  None of the shapes you give has the same second dimension as any other (except the two that don't have a second dimension at all, in which case it doesn't make much sense to use them to train or test).

Comment: Seems to work now -- going off what you said, it turns out I was building and fitting a separate CountVectorizer for both training and test, rather than fitting the training CV to the test set. Thanks!